# Sencha touch NestedList: How to stop audio player when closing detailsCard

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, html5-audio

I have an Ext.Audio component inside the detailsCard of a NestedList in my Sencha touch 2.1 app. 
I can't understand how to stop the audio stream when tapping the back button in the detailsCard. I also don't understand how to listen to the "back button tap event" only for the back button of the detailsCard. Here's my code:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Lead', {
extend: 'Ext.NestedList',
xtype: 'lead',
config: {
   title: 'Lead',
   iconCls:'lead',
       store: 'LeadStore',
   displayField: 'title',
   detailCard: { html: 'details' }
},
getDetailCard: function(node) {
          if (node) {
              return {
                  xtype: 'container',
                  layout: 'fit',
                  items: [
                      {
                          xtype: 'panel',
                          layout:'fit',
                          html: node.get('text')     
                      },
                      {               
                          xtype: 'audio',
                          docked: 'bottom',
                          url  : node.get('audio'),
                          autoPause: true,
                      },
                      ]
              }
          } 
     }
```

});

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your audio an `id` config for reference:

```
{               
    xtype: 'audio',
    docked: 'bottom',
    url  : node.get('audio'),
    autoPause: true,
    id: 'audio'
}
```

To handle back button you can use [back](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-event-back) event of your nested list along with [stop](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Audio-method-stop) method to stop your audio:

```
back: function() {
    Ext.getCmp('audio').stop();
}
```

You'l be safe if you use `itemId`.

```
itemId: audio
```

Then you can make use of [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query) to retrieve it:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#audio')[0].stop();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working but i get the following warning:
`[WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id ('audio') which has already been used. Please ensure the existing component has been destroyed ('Ext.Component#destroy()'.`
Every time (except the first one) i open a detailCard.
I tried the following without success:
`var player = Ext.getCmp('audio');
  if (player.isPlaying()) player.stop();
                // following not solving the problem
  player.destroy();`

Comment: For some reason it isn't working (and I don't get any error).
Thank you very much anyway I can live with that warning :)